# PHP Form submitting even when input is empty, and after submission doesn't stay (instead shows the php array)

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am a beginner in web development. I have a css and javascript all linked to my php form. Along with that i assigned the form action to another php file that would collect all form inputs after submission into a text file. Why is my page not staying after submission and instead shows the array? Why when there are empty inputs and the javascript alerts the form is still submitted in the php uploads? Thank you

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#defaultForm')
    .bootstrapValidator({
      live: 'enabled',
      fields: {
        'name[]': {
          validators: {
            notEmpty: {
              message: 'The textbox field is required'
            }
          }
        }
      },
      onSuccess: function(e, data) {
        alert('Success');
      }
    });
});

function registration() {

  var name = document.getElementById("name").value;
  var email = document.getElementById("email").value;
  var phone = document.getElementById("phone").value;
  var national = document.getElementById("national").value;
  var drivers = document.getElementById("drivers").value;
  var dob = document.getElementById("dob").value;
  var rqs = document.getElementById("rqs").value;
  var confirm = document.getElementById("confirm").value;

  var letters = /^[A-Za-z]+$/;
  var filter = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9\-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/;

  if (name == '') {
    alert('Please Enter Your Name');
  } else if (email == '') {
    alert('Please Enter Your Email Address');
  } else if (!filter.test(email)) {
    alert('Invalid email');
  } else if (national == '') {
    alert('Please Enter Your National ID Number.');
  } else if (drivers == '') {
    alert('Please Enter Your Drivers License Number.');
  } else if (dob == '') {
    alert('Date of Birth Required');
  } else if (rqs == '') {
    alert('Please Choose Request Type');
  } else if (confirm == '') {
    alert('Please Choose Confirmation Type');
  } else if (phone == '') {
    alert('Please Choose Confirmation Type');
  } else if (document.getElementById("phone").value.length < 11) {
    alert('Phone Number minimum length is 11');
  } else if (document.getElementById("phone").value.length > 11) {
    alert('Phone Number max length is 12');
  } else {
    alert('Thank you for submitting your request. You will be redirected back to NDTS.');
    window.location = "https://ndts-moi.000webhostapp.com/";
  }

  function clearFunc() {
    document.getElementById("name").value = "";
    document.getElementById("email").value = "";
    document.getElementById("phone").value = "";
    document.getElementById("national").value = "";
    document.getElementById("drivers").value = "";
    document.getElementById("dob").value = "";
    document.getElementById("rqs").value = "";
    document.getElementById("confirm").value = "";
  }

  function formvar() {
    var name = document.getElementById("name").value = "";
    var email = document.getElementById("email").value = "";
    var phone = document.getElementById("phone").value;
    var national = document.getElementById("national").value;
    var drivers = document.getElementById("drivers").value;
    var dob = document.getElementById("dob").value;
    var rqs = document.getElementById("rqs").value;
    var confirm = document.getElementById("confirm").value;

    function name(name) {
      var regex = (/[a-z]/);
      return regex.test(name);
    }

    function drivers(drivers) {
      var regex = /^[a-z][a-z0-9_]{4,20}$/gi;
      return regex.test(drivers);
    }

    function email(email) {
      var regex = /^([a-z0-9!#$%&'*+\-/=?^_`{|}~]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9!#$%&'*+\-/=?^_`{|}~]+)*)@((?:[a-z0-9]+(?:[a-z-0-9-]*)\.)+[a-z]{2,})$/gi;
      return regex.test(email);
    }

    function national(national) {
      if (typeof national != "string") {
        national = "" + national;
      }
      if (national.length < 16) {
        return 'National ID must be 16 digits';
      }

      function drivers(drivers) {
        if (typeof drivers != "string") {
          drivers = "" + drivers;
        }
        if (national.length < 16) {
          return 'National ID must be 16 digits';
        }

        function cpwd(confirmpass) {
          if (cpwd != pwd_expression) {
            return 'Passwords must match'
          }
          return true;
        }
      }

      function phone(phone) {
        var regex = /^\(?([0-9]{3})\)?[\-\.\s]?([0-9]{3})[\-\.\s]?([0-9]{4})$/g;
        return regex.test(phone);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@400;500;600&display=swap');
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  padding: 0 10px;
  min-height: 100vh;
  background: #296fd8;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

::selection {
  color: #fff;
  background: #715543;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 715px;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 10px 10px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
}

.wrapper header {
  font-size: 22px;
  font-weight: 600;
  padding: 20px 30px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.wrapper form {
  margin: 35px 30px;
}

.wrapper form.disabled {
  pointer-events: none;
  opacity: 0.7;
}

form .dbl-field {
  display: flex;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.dbl-field .field {
  height: 50px;
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  width: calc(100% / 2 - 13px);
}

.wrapper form i {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 18px;
  color: #ccc;
  font-size: 17px;
  pointer-events: none;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

form .field input,
form .message textarea {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  outline: none;
  padding: 0 18px 0 48px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.field input::placeholder,
.message textarea::placeholder {
  color: #ccc;
}

.field input:focus,
.message textarea:focus {
  padding-left: 47px;
  border: 2px solid #41536e;
}

.field input:focus~i,
.message textarea:focus~i {
  color: #0D6EFD;
}

form .message {
  position: relative;
}

form .message i {
  top: 30px;
  font-size: 20px;
}

form .message textarea {
  min-height: 130px;
  max-height: 230px;
  max-width: 100%;
  min-width: 100%;
  padding: 15px 20px 0 48px;
}

form .message textarea::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 0px;
}

.message textarea:focus {
  padding-top: 14px;
}

form .button-area {
  margin: 25px 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.button-area button {
  color: rgb(107, 83, 57);
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 13px 25px;
  background: #705643;
  transition: background 0.3s ease;
}

.button-area button:hover {
  background: #735a3f;
}

.button-area span {
  font-size: 17px;
  margin-left: 30px;
  display: none;
}

@media (max-width: 600px) {
  .wrapper header {
    text-align: center;
  }
  .wrapper form {
    margin: 35px 20px;
  }
  form .dbl-field {
    flex-direction: column;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
  }
  form .dbl-field .field {
    width: 100%;
    height: 45px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
  }
  form .message textarea {
    resize: none;
  }
  form .button-area {
    margin-top: 20px;
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  .button-area button {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 11px 0;
    font-size: 16px;
  }
  .button-area span {
    margin: 20px 0 0;
    text-align: center;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>NDTS - Request Form</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="request.css">
  <script src="javascript.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.3/css/all.min.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <header>NDTS Request Form</header>
    <form action="upload2.php" method="post" id="form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <div class="dbl-field">
        <div class="field">
          <input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Enter Your Full Name">
          <i class='fas fa-user'></i>
        </div>
        <div class="field">
          <input type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Enter Your Email Address">
          <i class='fas fa-envelope'></i>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="dbl-field">
        <div class="field">
          <input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" placeholder="Enter Your Phone #">
          <i class='fas fa-phone-alt'></i>
        </div>
        <div class="field">
          <input type="text" name="national" id="national" placeholder="Enter Your National ID #">
          <i class='fas fa-globe'></i>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="dbl-field">
        <div class="field">
          <input type="text" name="drivers" id="drivers" placeholder="Enter Drivers' License #">
          <i class='fas fa-globe'></i>
        </div>
        <div class="field">
          <input type="date" name="dob" id="dob" placeholder="Enter Your Date of Birth">
          <i class='fas fa-globe'></i>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="message">
        <label for="requests">Request Type</label>
        <select name="rqs" id="rqs">
          <option value="License Renewal">License Renewal</option>
          <option value="Traffic Violations">Traffic Violations</option>
          <option value="Replace ID">Replace National ID/Drivers License</option>
          <option value="Buy/AuctionPlate">Buy/Auction Your Plate</option>
          <option value="Other Requests">Other Request</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div class="message">
        <label for="confimation">Recieve Confimation Via</label>
        <select name="confirm" id="confirm">
          <option value="E-Mail">E-Mail</option>
          <option value="Text Message">Text Message</option>
          <option value="Phone Call">Phone Call</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div class="button-area">
        <input type="submit" name="send" id="send" value="Send" onclick="registration()" action="upload2.php">
        <input type="reset" name="clear" id="clear" value="clear" onclick="clearFunc()">
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to stackoverflow. Please include your PHP code in order for me to be able to debug it and help you.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.